# How to fix CORS error in react + vite from front end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api, vite

So I am trying to fetch data from an API but it keeps showing a CORS error no matter what I try...
[image]

It is important to know that It is an external API and I don't have access to the server code. Only to my front-end code.

My code is the following:

`

```
const [contaminacion, setcontaminacion] = useState([]);

 
  const obtenerDatos = async (url) => {
    const datan = await fetch(url, {
      mode: "cors",
      method:"GET",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
      },
    });
    console.log(datan);
    const dataParsed = await datan.json();
    setcontaminacion(dataParsed.results);
  };

  
  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerDatos(
      "https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/api/red/especial/contaminacionfondo/estacion/07"
    );
    
  }, []);
```

`
I read in an old post (more than 5 years old) that I could use a proxy with Heroku, but in the comments they say that Heroku doesn't serve to this purpose anymore.

I have tried to set a proxy in my vite.config.js folder but it is not working for me and I don't know if I am doing it properly or not.

That's what I wrote:
`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    proxy:{
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/api/red/especial/contaminacionfondo/estacion/07',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
      }
      
    }

  },
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

`
What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need an API key to access the API, no? https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/altaUsuario?

Comment: I was able to query pollution data from AEMET (Spanish Meteorological Agency).  You must request an [API key](https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/altaUsuario?), which is free.  Note that the response returns a data url ('datos') which must be called to get the current pollution data.  And the data is in FINN format, which is a text format used for environmental data (not json).  See [redes-especiales : Redes Especiales](https://opendata.aemet.es/dist/index.html?#/redes-especiales) and [Ejemplo en NodeJS Request](https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/ejemProgramas?)

Comment: I got the key and I used it to get end-point url but I'm not using it anywhere in my code. I didn't use nodeJs example. There was a javascript and a nodejs example. Is nodejs one better? Oh, ty I didn't know anything about FINN format. I'll double check everything!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/inicio APIs without an API key.

You will have to register on the site, get an API key and using that API make the request. When registering for the API key, you will be asked to provide the domain of your application. This domain will be returned in the   `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and your client will not get the CORS error anymore.

Comment: I got the key and I used it to get the end point url. I as far as I know I wasn't asked for the domain of my app. I'll double check it anyway. Thanks!